# Run GDAL on android and perform operations

Tags: python, gdal, android

Could one run gdal on android devices to perform some GIS operation, like viewshed, contours, etc?

Comment: I think to try it with Kivy. There is python for Android project, there are repices for many python libraries but not gdal. I will search how to create recipes for gdal. Then it can be possible to use gdal for Android :)